# Amazon's 1-Click Check Out : any feedback?

Tags: business-cycles

Does anyone have feedbacks or analysis on Amazon's 1-Click Check Out ?

Any numbers about the conversion rates (before/after using the 1-click checkout button) , etc. ?

[This page](https://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button/) is about a $300 Million per year magic button, but doesn't mention which site is using it.

Thanks.

Zaky

Comment: Could you clarify your question? E.g. what is a "transormation rate"? (Even with and added f I don't know what you mean.)

Comment: Hey Denesp, I meant conversion rate. Question edited.

Comment: I don't understand. What are the economic principles you are asking about? As it stands you don't seem to be asking about economic principles at all - you're just looking for a data point. We do have a sister site for such enquiries - [opendata.se]. But I'd have thought the data you're after is commercially sensitive.

Comment: Well it's also a UX Design point... I thought economic was also about business. My bad ! Thanks though.